# How to get post body look same as my visual editor?

Tags: posts, visual-editor

When I apply the format and styles such as bold and `<br/>` on visual editor it looks bit nicer.
But when I see that on blog post it looks totally different.

I do not use any styles for p tag in my style sheet.

How can I just get the same look of post with styles I applied in visual editor when I see the post on the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the editor uses its own stylesheet which might be quite different from the one on your theme.

If you are willing to dig into the code it would make sense to make a stylesheet for the editor. See this for details http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_editor_style

Comment: thanks for that. that works. also I've found another solution TinyMCE Advance editor.

Answer (score 0):

give your post a style, and give it this value:

```
margin-top: 15px;
```

Comment: ha? I do not get that? to which class I wanna apply that style?